# DomainClass.where queries, authorization, and filtering

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm looking into using Grails and accessing MongoDB using GORM.

Say I have a domain class named BlogPost, but a specific user is only allowed to see certain blogs posts.

Now, In a controller action I can easily do something like BlogPost.where {}, but that will return all blog posts.

I need a centralized mechanism to filter which domain objects are returned when a controller performs a query.

The plugin used is http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use GORM events "onLoad" in domain class and apply filter there. For example:

```
Class BlogPost{
   String content    
   String viewableByRole //it might be another domain for roles/string/enum as per your requirement
   ....
   def onLoad() {
       //apply your condition here
} 
}
```

See here: [GORM Events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

Or you can define method in service class or in domain class to apply the filter. For example,

```
...
   def getAllPost() {
       def currentRole = take_role_from_security_plugin_like_shiro_or_spring_security_session etc
       return BlogPost.findAllByViewableByRole(currentRole)               

}
...
```

Actually your question encompasses a big scope. You could get better suggestion if question is a bit more specific.